# Excel 2013 - Problems splitting cell containing two decimal numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I need to separate values that look like this and are in one column in an excel spreadsheet.

48.116667, 11.55

I though this would be easy and did this: Select the column, click on (Data Ribbon) - Text to columns

next I choose "delimited", in the next window I choose "comma" as the delimiter and in the preview everything looks fine. I see 2 columns with these numbers

48.116667  and in the next column 11.55

I click next and in the Data Preview I see that both columns that are to be created have the "General" Format.

Still the output looks correct and like in the previous window.

I click "Finish" and get this (can´t post a picture)

in the formula bar it says for my left number: 48116667

In the table it shows in the left column: 48.116.667 (centered right)(number format)
And it says in the right column (correctly): 11.5 (General) (centered left)

The left number now a 8 digit number without any separators in the data entry field above and with 2 dots in the table itself. The second number is shown correctly.

I need both numbers to look just like the right number and without any error sign next to 
the field. Just a "normal" number field with comma OR Point (doesn´t matter which) as my 
decimal sign and no additional points or signs in any number.

What I have tried:

In Options-Advanced I deselected "Automatically add decimal point".

This might also be relevant:
In the Options-Advanced it also says Use system separators (which is active) and there:
comma for Decimal separator
and
Point for Thousand Separator

It might also be relevant that I use Windows 7 German Edition as my Operating System.

Would be great if could help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

German OS is probably the issue. Looks like the period is used as the thousand separator on your system. Try changing the options, either in the system or just in Excel, to use the point for decimal separator while you do this operation.

Comment: Thanks, I just deselected "Use system separators" in the Excel Advanced Options and then selected Point as decimal separators in the advanced Text import settings in step 3 of the "text to columns" operation. Thanks for the hint :)